# Alternative for "Don't quote me on that"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, phrase-usage

I was looking for a better alternative for "Don't quote me on that" phrase.

Context : My (International) friend came to visit us and saw us doing some rituals. She asked me about its history. Now I had a vague memory of my grandpa telling me that history. So I told her, and added "But please don't quote me on that, There may be more than just this reason".

I want to use some better phrase in future, that makes the person believe me, but just double check the facts. Because she (and even I) actually felt like I was making that history up after I said "Don't quote me". Can someone suggest some?

Comment: How about, “Well, I have a vague memory of my Grandpa telling me that…”

Comment: Perhaps "If I remember correctly, my grandpa told me ..." Or "I seem to remember my grandpa telling me..." You can always add "But double check me if you want to be sure." Also, your memory could be right, but your grandpa wrong!

Comment: Another option is "but I could be wrong"